# defrosting homemade frozen bread

Tags: bread, freezing, food-preservation, defrosting

I made several loaves of bread 7 days prior to use due to time constraint, so I decided to freeze them after fully cooled, 8 hours after cooked.

Normally with frozen bread I would let out at room temperature while sealed for 4 to 5 hours.   Will bread be fresh if I assemble sandwiches with frozen bread, wrap air-tight, and wait 6 hours prior to eating? If not, what method would be best to retain freshness of bread, meats, and cheeses assembled in sandwiches?

Comment: Will they be refrigerated in the interim?

Comment: Please [don't refrigerate bread](http://www.seriouseats.com/2014/06/does-refrigeration-really-ruin-bread.html)!

Comment: No - the bread, nor the sandwiches would not be refrigerated.  They will be sitting in a bag in a ski lodge.     Please forego any comments regarding food safety after 2 hours I am only concerned with taste in this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a possibility, here's what I do for make-ahead sandwiches with (previously) frozen bread. I'd suggest only a couple things beyond what you are planning.

After the bread is out of the oven and fully cooled (8 hours or over-night as you did), I **slice before freezing**. This allows me to take slices out of the freezer a few at a time. (As an alternative, you could take the bread out several hours ahead of time, then thaw enough to slice; I find this less convenient. Slicing frozen bread is something I try to avoid!)

Once out of the freezer, I **toast the bread**. This both gets the chill off and gives the bread some added freshening and ability to stand up to holding contents for some time (e.g., so the bread doesn't get as soggy). Making sandwiches directly with pre-sliced, frozen bread is possible, but I expect it would exacerbate the sogginess.

Assemble the sandwiches and wrap in plastic, foil, or a bag (as you suggest) as tightly as convenient. This procedure, for me, works adequately for several hours of make-ahead.

Comment: do you actually toast the bread or do you place it toaster just until defrosted?

Comment: I think defrosting alone will help some, but usually I "actually toast" lightly to give the bread a little more ability to stand up to contact with sandwich contents for a longer period of time. After several hours, the bread probably won't even seem very "toasted" as such.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea.  I've been doing this for a long time. I let the bread cool after taking it out of pans (usually an hour or two) then partially freeze it. Then slice it all. I do have a met slicer I use, then into bags & quickly back in the freezer.Take out as many slices as U need.